# How to make a stacked bar chart with 3 categories inside the bars?

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

Hello I would like to make a plot stacked bar charts. For each month, I would like to have the percentage of success of an expedition for each category (small mountains, medium mountains, big mountains). So a barplot with 12 bars with each time three categories inside. I started by making this code but I'm stuck. Can you help me?

```
import pandas as pd 
members = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/members.csv")
peaks = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/peaks.csv")
success = members[members["success"]==True]
conditions = {
'small': peaks['height_metres'] < 6226.5,
'medium': peaks['height_metres'] < 7031.25,
}
peaks['catégorie_montagne'] = np.select(conditions.values(), conditions.keys(), default='big')
members_cat_montagne = pd.merge(members, peaks[["peak_id", "catégorie_montagne"]], on = "peak_id", how ="inner")
success_cat_montagne = pd.merge(success, peaks[["peak_id", "catégorie_montagne"]], on = "peak_id", how ="inner")
```

Comment: how is `peaks` defined? and `success`?

Comment: I have updated my code